# appengine python backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I'm trying to run some code on Appengine using dynamic backends (python), but I find [Appengine dynamic backends documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Startup) to be inadequate. Does anyone have any sample code regarding how this can be done?

I have already configured my backends.yaml like so

```
backends: 
- name: fileupload-backend
  options: dynamic
  start: backend_handler.py
```

And I understand that dynamic backends run when Appengine sends a start request to /_ah/start, then run when they receive a request from the application and stops when they receive no further requests from the application. But how do I write code in my backends_handler.py in order to prompt appengine to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a nice example on how to use Google App Engine Backends, you can take a look at [Google App Engine Tutorial - Code Lab Exercise 8: Queues and Backends](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise8.html).

This tutorial presents an example on how to user Task Queues and Backends.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for something in python. I found the Google IO session on it to be very good: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/app-engine-backends.html

Comment: The Backend API is deprecated as of March 13, 2014 as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/)

Answer (score 1):

You've slightly misunderstood the point of the `start` option. This is the script that is automatically invoked when AppEngine hits the `/_ah/start` - it's not responsible for calling it, it's responsible for responding to that call. Most of the time you won't need this: it's really for when your backend needs specific things to be set up on startup. It's perfectly OK in fact to not handle the `/_ah/start` call at all, and let it respond with a 404 - that's enough to trigger the backend to start up.

If you're confused about how to actually run code on the backend, your best bet is to configure a task queue to run on that backend with the `target` parameter, and then get your frontend code to trigger a task on that queue.

Comment: In my case if left to not handle the `/_ah/start` it will always raise Errors: 4xx & 5xx client in logs so I would prefer to configure a task for it as suggested.